# Execute command on commit in Windows Setup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-services, windows-installer

This may be an obvious thing for most, but I am having a hard time seeing it or understanding how to do it.

I have a Setup project in Visual Studio. The project installs a Windows Service, but I need to launch a configuration utility before the service starts.

I have handled the configuration bit in the `onStart()` method of the service project, but I can't seem to figure out how to start the service after the installer completes.

Is there some way to issue a system command, such as a `NET START`, after the installer successfully completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to reconsider using the Setup project it's very limited in capability and Microsoft has announced that it won't be available in future versions of Visual Studio.

I have two suggestions if you want the best installer possible:

1) Reconsider using the InstallUtil custom action to create and start your service.  Windows Installer supports this natively.  The only reason you are forced to use the custom action is because Visual Studio setup projects don't expose the underlying capability of MSI to create services.  Switching to a tool like InstallShield 2010 Limited Edition of Windows Installer XML would solve that problem.

2) Redesign your service to not require the configuration utlity to run before it starts.  Allow it to go into an idle state until the configuration utility has run and notified the service that it may now begin processing.  Put the utility in the start menu and/or run it at the end of the install.

Comment: I think I'm going to look into using an alternate installer, because this is a project for an application that will be deployed to customers, with the customer being left to install and configure. If the configuration utility isn't used, then the likelihood of the customer actually completing the process is pretty limited.

Comment: I ended up going with NSIS for this. It is a bit cumbersome getting started, but I think it's going to work fine for this project. Thanks for letting me know about the weakness of a setup project!